# Changing the pause required before Voice Commands in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Is there any way to change the pause required before Voice Commands in OS X Yosemite? I.e. if I want to dictate "hello world" then move the cursor on the left, I'll have to say "hello world move left": I would like to define how long the pause between "hello world" and "move left" should be in order for Yosemite to recognize that "move left" is a voice command.

E.g. in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I can change it like this:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.